# Using a peer dependency in npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm

I have momentjs listed as a peer dependency in a npm package full of utility functions. One of these functions uses moment.

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "moment": "2.x.x"
},
```

Here's a simplified look at where moment is being used:

```
import moment from 'moment'

export default function formatDate(someDate) {
  return moment(someDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY')
}
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
"main": "dist/index.js",
"types": "dist/index.d.ts",
"files": [
    "dist"
],
"scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "publish-free": "npm publish --access public"
},
```

When I run "npm run build" I get an error in the terminal saying "Cannot find module 'moment'".

I am currently testing the package by using npm link to connect it to my main project where I have moment installed but I can't get past the build stage.

Comment: You should install it as a dev dependency as well as marking it a peer dependency for others.

Comment: Try to run `tsc --preserveSymlinks` as build script.

Comment: Adding as a dev dependency seems to be the consensus and worked for me! Thanks.